# How to get doc2vec to reliably work with UMAP?

Tags: pyspark, doc2vec

I have the following pyspark code where I build a Doc2vev model and run UMAP on it. Only sometimes the last UMAP line will throw the error "Cannot assign slice from input of different size".

I can try to specify a random starting seed to find one that always converges for this specific document input, but I really want to improve the model code so it can take any similar document with different data and always converge without me having to manually find a starting seed that works.

What is it about the doc2vec model that makes it sometimes not work with the UMAP function that I can improve?

```
train_corpus = [gensim.models.doc2vec.TaggedDocument([word for word in agg_corpus_dict[i]['doc'] if word is not None], [str(agg_corpus_dict[i]['id'])]) for i in range(len(agg_corpus_dict))]

model = gensim.models.doc2vec.Doc2Vec(vector_size=100, min_count=20, epochs=20, workers=4)

progress_per_value = 1000  
model.build_vocab(train_corpus, progress_per=progress_per_value)

model.train(train_corpus, total_examples=model.corpus_count, epochs=model.epochs)

model.make_cum_table()
model.save('<model_dir>')
```

```
# Load fitted doc2vec model
doc2vec_model = gensim.models.doc2vec.Doc2Vec.load('<model_dir>')
```

```
reducer = umap.UMAP().fit(doc2vec_model.dv.vectors)
```

I've tried random starting seeds.

Comment: That error means the size of inputs are different, can you check length of vectors for faulty seed? Also, this is totally unrelated and I might be wrong but you can't save an UMAP model and then load it on another PC, weirdly enough. :^)

Comment: Shapes are always the same when UMAP complains about slices. It seems to do with the actual vectors in the data. I want each UMAP model to be relative to the input doc2vec.

Answer (score 0):

Editing your question to show the **full error** you receive, including all the lines of traceback showing involved lines-of-code/files, will help answerers determine what's going on.

If the exact same code, using the exact same `Doc2Vec` model, sometimes succeeds & sometimes fails, that implies some instability in the `UMAP` code. (Still, seeing the whole erro/traceback might offer clues.)

If, on the other hand, it fails reliably on some frozen `Doc2Vec` models, but not others, your should add extra output to determine what's different about the cases that it succeeds & fails. For example, `print(d2v_model.dv.vectors.shape)` before the line that sometimes fails, & examine (or share in your question) the outputs from both successful & failing runs.

If that shows no obvious difference/coding-error between working and non-working cases, I suppose there's a chance the `UMAP` code is sensitive in some way to the exact values inside the `Doc2Vec` vectors. I wouldn't normally expect that – in the usual case, all vectors have nonzero dimensions, and I'd expect an algorithm that works on one set of such dimensions to work on others.

But I suppose it might be possible, especially if you're running on a small or quirky amount of data, that some runs are leaving some vector dimensions in weird states – like lots of `0.0` values – and that's perhaps creating problems for the `UMAP` step, if it assumes otherwise. So if nothing else improves things, that'd be something else to check.